# System.out.println("help" + help);

Tags: java

Can I print all strings in a different paragraph?
For example:

```
System.out.print("name");
name= SC.nextLine();
System.out.print("age");
age= SC.nextLine();
System.out.println("Name: " + name);
System.out.println("Age: " + age);
```

And then, when I run them, this will show up:

```
Name: (Type Name)
Age: (Type Age)

Name: JavaDotExE
Age: 20
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Is this all you need `System.out.println("")`? Just an extra blank line?

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `System.out.println()` will add extra blank line to console.